# How do I get out of this freaking loop

Tags: java

I understand that while the state is true the loop will keep running.  I thought if I simply typed in loop=false, after the } bracket for the loop I could continue to code.  Obviously I was wrong, it wont run anything.  SOMEONE please show me how to get out of this hell of a while loop.

```
System.out.println("You total balance is 0.00, "
                + "please deposit coins and type done when finished");

        while(loop){
            if (input.hasNextInt()){
                deposit = input.nextBigDecimal();}
                String change = input.next();

        switch (change){

        case "quarter":
            balance= quarter.multiply(deposit);
            total=total.add(balance);
            System.out.println("Your balance is "+ total +" :Make addiontal deposit(s)");
            break;

        case "dime": 
            balance=dime.multiply(deposit);
            total=total.add(balance);
            System.out.println("Your balance is "+ total +" :Make addiontal deposit(s)");
            break;
        case "nickel":
            balance=nickel.multiply(deposit);
            total=total.add(balance);
            System.out.println("Your balance is "+ total +" :Make addiontal deposit(s)");
            break;
        case "penny":
            balance=penny.multiply(deposit);
            total=total.add(balance);
            System.out.println("Your balance is "+ total +" :Make addiontal deposit(s)");
            break;
        case"done":
            System.out.println("Your total is $"+total);
            fee=total.multiply(feeRate);
            System.out.println("The exchance fee is 9.1% which amounts to $"+fee);
            grandTotal=total.subtract(fee);
            System.out.println("Your total balance minus the exchange fee is $"+grandTotal);

            break;

        default: System.out.println("There is a issue at "+change);}

            } System.out.println("4");

        }

}
```

Comment: That is why it is called a loop ... once in the loop, the execution stays in the loop until the break condition is met. The loop variable **must** be set from within the loop and not **after** the loop.

Answer (score 5):

The key is to change the loop variable so that it becomes false and will thus have you exit the while loop. So change the loop variable in the `case "done"` block. In that block, set `loop = false;`

```
    case"done":
        System.out.println("Your total is $"+total);
        fee=total.multiply(feeRate);
        System.out.println("The exchance fee is 9.1% which amounts to $"+fee);
        grandTotal=total.subtract(fee);
        System.out.println("Your total balance minus the exchange fee is $"+grandTotal);

        loop = false;   // ************  add this ************

        break;
```

Keep in mind that the key concept is that the thing that is causing the loop to continue **must** be changed somehow **within** the loop itself. Otherwise the while loop will never end.

Answer (score 3):

Three methods to break a loop.

A) set your flag variable to `false`:

```
loop = false;
```

Since you already have this variable, this is the much nicer (and simpler) approach.

B) use a labeled break.

```
label: while(true) {
  // ...
  switch(something) {
    break label; // Without a label, it would only leave the switch!
  }
}
```

Some people will frown upon this last solution, because it is essentially a "goto".

C) use more modular code.

In many cases, the much cleaner way is to use *methods*. Then you can have "break" to exit an inner loop or switch and `return` to actually leave the subprocedure and return a result.

This leads to easier-to-understand code, and the semantics of a `return` are often much more appropriate than those of a `break`.

Comment: using `labels` in coding is not preferred, it makes your code unclear

Comment: But to give Anony credit, he does mention the down-side. The answer is well-reasoned. 1+

Comment: @MoshErsan, Using labels does not make code unclear.  What makes code unclear is nesting statements so deeply that you _need_ a label to indicate which construct you want to break out of.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop will continue to go round until the loop variable is set to false. In the "done" case, just set that to false. That way, it won't loop back around again.

```
        case"done":
            System.out.println("Your total is $"+total);
            fee=total.multiply(feeRate);
            System.out.println("The exchance fee is 9.1% which amounts to $"+fee);
            grandTotal=total.subtract(fee);
            System.out.println("Your total balance minus the exchange fee is $"+grandTotal);
            loop = false; // This is the line to add.
            break;
```

Comment: Don't just dump code where we have to look for the explanation. Show what you did and explain why you did it in a way that we can see it clearly. There's no need to copy 50 lines if you only change 1.

Comment: But this is not a convincing reason to down vote a correct answer, they should comment on it explaining; that like you did.

Comment: I have now added an explanation. There is also a comment in the code, it should be fairly clear. 5 down votes, well done community :). "Thanks for helping" would be welcome, what you are saying is "naff off - how dare you help". Thanks for saying how to improve it to the 1 person that did, it has been improved..  no need for the down voting.

Comment: @NutterzUK: it's definitely better now, but you should really just remove all the irrelevant code. It serves no purpose other than hiding your actual change. Mosh: they don't *have* to and they might as well show agreement by upvoting my comment.

Comment: It is a correct answer and should receive an +1 vote, and now has received 2, mine and someone else's.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding only putting in a few lines that I need of code, I will remember that for the future, and thanks EVERYONE FOR THE HELP!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the value of the variable `loop` inside oft the while loop to `false`.

I guess this should be in the case when the user types `done`. So in this case add the following line:

```
loop = false;
```

anywhere in the `case "done":` block